# Android fragment views not rendering as required

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my current layout:

[image]

I know it is black but my phone was facing down. It is supposed to be a camera preview. Anyway, whatever renders on the small one renders on the big one.

The small camera preview, takes half of the screen's height and 1/4 of screen's width (landscape mode). Now proportionally it should fill the rest of the screen ( the second half) but it doesn't. You can see the problem is that it is not using all the height, there are 2 green lines.

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainPreviewActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/center_dummy_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/clean_preview_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/center_dummy_view"
            android:background="@color/LightGrey"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listOptionsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/center_dummy_view"
            android:background="@color/LightGrey"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/processed_preview_fragment_container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can see the `FrameLayout`, `@+id/processed_preview_fragment_container` has a `fill_parent` layout_height value.

The fragments view is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.apps.foo.bar.fragments.ProcessedPreviewFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/processed_preview_img_view"
        android:background="@color/LimeGreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using below code as fragment view since imageview default property to draw image at center so it doesn't scale image according to view height and width. so you need to specify scale type for image. i have used "fitXY" in this image will cover full height and width but image may be stretch so you can change it according to your requirement

```
    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.apps.alexs7.pointop.fragments.ProcessedPreviewFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/processed_preview_img_view"
    android:background="@color/LimeGreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: did not know this scaleType existed. I will give it a try and let you know!

Comment: Thanks it worked, although it seems a bit stretched but I can work with that.